# Spring boot and Jira REST API give dependency errors in maven

Tags: rest, jira, jira-rest-api, jira-rest-java-api

**project main dependencies**

```
  <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>1.2.1.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>

<dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-actuator</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-data-cassandra</artifactId>
            <version>1.1.2.RELEASE</version><!--$NO-MVN-MAN-VER$-->
       </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.mail</groupId>
            <artifactId>mail</artifactId>
            <version>1.4.3</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.rallydev.rest</groupId>
            <artifactId>rally-rest-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.1.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>log4j-core</artifactId>
            <version>2.2</version><!--$NO-MVN-MAN-VER$-->
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>joda-time</groupId>
            <artifactId>joda-time</artifactId>
            <version>2.7</version>
        </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

**JIRA REST API dependencies**

```
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>junit</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
        <version>4.8.2</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.sun.jersey</groupId>
        <artifactId>jersey-json</artifactId>
        <version>1.5</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.sun.jersey</groupId>
        <artifactId>jersey-client</artifactId>
        <version>1.9</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.atlassian.jira</groupId>
        <artifactId>jira-rest-java-client-api</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.atlassian.jira</groupId>
        <artifactId>jira-rest-java-client-core</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.google.guava</groupId>
        <artifactId>guava</artifactId>
        <version>14.0-rc1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.codehaus.jettison</groupId>
        <artifactId>jettison</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>slf4j-simple</artifactId>
        <version>1.6.4</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>commons-io</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-io</artifactId>
        <version>2.4</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

**error**

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/http/nio/NHttpMessageParserFactory
    at org.apache.http.impl.nio.conn.PoolingClientAsyncConnectionManager.createClientAsyncConnectionFactory(PoolingClientAsyncConnectionManager.java:96)
```

JIRA Rest api client and its dependencies conflicting with Spring-boot-starter-parent, spring-boot-web. Can somebody guide me how to resolve these conflicts.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Add the following props to your pom

```
<properties>
    <httpasyncclient.version>4.0-beta3-atlassian-1</httpasyncclient.version>
    <httpclient.version>4.2.1-atlassian-2</httpclient.version>
</properties>
```

For your reference, my full pom looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
     xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
     xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

<groupId>com.company</groupId>
<artifactId>junk</artifactId>
<version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>

<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>1.3.5.RELEASE</version>
</parent>

<properties>
    <httpasyncclient.version>4.0-beta3-atlassian-1</httpasyncclient.version>
    <httpclient.version>4.2.1-atlassian-2</httpclient.version>
</properties>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>junit</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
        <version>4.8.2</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.sun.jersey</groupId>
        <artifactId>jersey-json</artifactId>
        <version>1.5</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.sun.jersey</groupId>
        <artifactId>jersey-client</artifactId>
        <version>1.9</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.atlassian.jira</groupId>
        <artifactId>jira-rest-java-client-api</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.atlassian.jira</groupId>
        <artifactId>jira-rest-java-client-core</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.google.guava</groupId>
        <artifactId>guava</artifactId>
        <version>14.0-rc1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.codehaus.jettison</groupId>
        <artifactId>jettison</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>slf4j-simple</artifactId>
        <version>1.6.4</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>commons-io</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-io</artifactId>
        <version>2.4</version>
    </dependency>



    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-actuator</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-data-cassandra</artifactId>
        <version>1.1.2.RELEASE</version><!--$NO-MVN-MAN-VER$-->
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.mail</groupId>
        <artifactId>mail</artifactId>
        <version>1.4.3</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.rallydev.rest</groupId>
        <artifactId>rally-rest-api</artifactId>
        <version>2.1.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>log4j-core</artifactId>
        <version>2.2</version><!--$NO-MVN-MAN-VER$-->
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>joda-time</groupId>
        <artifactId>joda-time</artifactId>
        <version>2.7</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>



<repositories>
    <repository>
        <id>atlassian-public</id>
        <url>https://m2proxy.atlassian.com/repository/public</url>
        <snapshots>
            <enabled>true</enabled>
            <updatePolicy>daily</updatePolicy>
            <checksumPolicy>warn</checksumPolicy>
        </snapshots>
        <releases>
            <enabled>true</enabled>
            <checksumPolicy>warn</checksumPolicy>
        </releases>
    </repository>
</repositories>

<pluginRepositories>
    <pluginRepository>
        <id>atlassian-public</id>
        <url>https://m2proxy.atlassian.com/repository/public</url>
        <releases>
            <enabled>true</enabled>
            <checksumPolicy>warn</checksumPolicy>
        </releases>
        <snapshots>
            <checksumPolicy>warn</checksumPolicy>
        </snapshots>
    </pluginRepository>
</pluginRepositories>
```

Comment: Somaiah Kumbera. i appreciate your effort for creating a github repo. Your code worked perfectly when i tried. But it got some conflicts with my existing set of spring libraries. If possible can you tell me how use your set of lib with my existing libraries

Comment: You edited the question and changed the situation. Would help others in the future if you had the original question.  For the dependency issue you can create a new question

Comment: Ya. I didn't think about that. sorry

Comment: Dont bother reverting the edits. I placed my answer in the duplicate question for posterity. FYI that question is http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36864240/jrjc-is-throwing-noclassdeffound-exceptions/37749045. I have also answered your new question here ;)